# Hyperledger 1.0.0 Beta Issue on Ubuntu runnin g sample tls: oversized record received with length 20527"

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm running the sample tutorial with the 1.0.0 Beta using docker.

The sample runs fine on MAC OS Sierra 10.12.4 and it works like a charm.

When I try to run the same Tuto on my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-86-generic x86_64) box, I'm facing a strange issue

> Error: Error connecting due to rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: oversized record received with length 20527"

I'm running the sample e2e_cli:

`/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli$ ./network_setup.sh up`

Full Error Message =>

```
2017-06-14 06:43:26.345 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP
2017-06-14 06:43:26.345 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-06-14 06:43:26.348 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 006 Failed to dial orderer.example.com:7050: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: oversized record received with length 20527"; please retry.
Error: Error connecting due to  rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: oversized record received with length 20527"
```

Thanks for your help